# How to install pdfkit/wkhtmltopdf in Python Azure Function Docker Container?

Tags: python, azure, docker, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I'm using the library **pdfkit** to render a PDF from an HTML template. The library is just a wrapper for **wkhtmltopdf** and that is a pain in the butt to install.

The generic Dockerfile given by the python Azure Function is this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:3.0-python3.8

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot
```

I'm pretty new to Docker, but I understand that the pdfkit library can just be added to my requirements. I just don't know how to deal with wkhtmltopdf.

I saw this solution, but how would I work this solution into my Dockerfile?

```
# Create image based on the official openjdk 8-jre-alpine image from the dockerhub
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

# Install wkhtmltopdf
RUN apk add --no-cache wkhtmltopdf

ENTRYPOINT ["wkhtmltopdf"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to install the `wkhtmltopdf` in the docker you can do it using a package manager of the image you are using.
- Assuming you are using a Debian based image you can run the following  command:

```
sudo  apt-get  install  wkhtmltopdf
```

- Now your `Dockerfile`  Should look like this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.10

RUN  sudo  apt-get  install  wkhtmltopdf

ENV  AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot  \

AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY  requirements.txt  /

RUN  pip  install  -r  /requirements.txt

COPY  .  /home/site/wwwroot
```

- Except the installation of `wkhtmltopdf` the above `DockerFile`  is autogenerated using the command

```
func init . --docker
```

Refer this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=in-process,bash,azure-cli&pivots=programming-language-python) on deploying azure function using docker